# Ansible Version Forcing

Tags: ansible

We have multiple versions of ansible(2.3,2.3.0,2.8.6) we want to use a particular version '2.8.6'.

But whenever ansible execution starts, it uses a different version 2.4.2.0. If we check ansible --version it is ansible-playbook 2.4.2.0.

Is ansible and ansible-playbook versions are same?
How to force a version in ansible execution?

Please give your inputs.

Comment: you can use the python's virtual environment for instance.

Comment: Please provide steps / documentation for virtual environment setup for multiple ansible installation...

Comment: one ansible per virtual env. 1 installing virt env, 2. pip install ansible=2.7, 3. source /path/to/bin/activate/ot/the given/virt/env 4. ansible --version

Answer (score 3):

Ansible is well-known to subtly break compatibility around variables, roles, includes and delegation. Therefore, it's considered to be the best practice to assert an Ansible version in a playbook before doing anything.

There are few things to assure:

1. Those checks should survive --tags option.
2. Those checks should survive --limit
3. Those checks should be relatively fast and cause as less verbosity as possible.

My current solution is:

1. Create playbook `version_check.yaml`
2. `- import_playbook: version_check.yaml` at the beginning of each playbook. (*each*, this is important, trust me).

version_check.yaml content (ansible 2.5+):

```
- hosts: all, localhost
  gather_facts: false
  run_once: true
  tasks:
  - name: Check ansible version
    assert:
      that:
        - "ansible_version.full is version('2.8.0', '>=')"
        - "ansible_version.full is version('2.9.0', '<')"
      msg: >
          Use Ansible to 2.8 to run this playbook
    delegate_to: localhost
    tags:
    - always
```

As you can see, there are a lot here.

1. run_once do this once per Ansible run.
2. gather_facts: false speed it up a bit.
3. It is assigned to 'all, localhost', basically guaranee that it's in Ansible runlist regardless of any `--limit`
4. It has tag `always` almost guarantee to run in the case of use `--tags`. The single uncovered hole here is to use `--skip always` (which is insane).

There is an older answer with older syntax for versions (below 2.5):

```
- hosts: all, localhost
  gather_facts: false
  run_once: true
  tasks:
  - name: Check ansible version
    assert:
      that:
        - "ansible_version.full | version_compare('2.8.0', '>=')"
        - "ansible_version.full | version_compare('2.9.0', '<')"
      msg: >
          Use Ansible to 2.8 to run this playbook
    delegate_to: localhost
    tags:
    - always
```

It's hard to say which version to use. If you are afraid of very old ansible, `version_compare` is better than `version`, but if you are sure it's at least 2.5+, you can use newer `version` syntax.